# Apache 2.4 and TOR

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redirect, tor

I am hosting an information and forum site and have had a lot of users ask for TOR access but I am having an issue adding it, when connecting from the server IP, everything is fine, the site is fully working, when connecting via a TOR hostname the site is completely broken and all links direct to 127.0.0.1 instead of the proper Domain. All assets are dynamic.

I have no `.htaccess` and VirtualHost is only changed in

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/forum
```

`apache2.conf` has

```
LogLevel debug
/var/www/
AllowOverride All
```

Mod_rewrite is enabled but trying to create a working arg has failed, do I need to use VirtualHost, `.htaccess`, or a combination to redirect all 127.0.0.1 to the correct domain? And how can I do so and maintain the ability to have multiple mirrors?

Comment: did you added the onion as serveralias? since you did not post any logs or configs our glassball is saying... something could it be 

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your web application, not with Apache. Check there first.

Comment: What can I do to fix the web application to work with tor? I have all my assets dynamic already as the IP changes to 127.0.0.1 before all the links, but I need it to change to the actual tor domain